# Firebase Authentication - Sign In with Apple: nonce returns nil

Tags: swiftui, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in, apple-cryptokit, swift5.6

Strange. I'm clearly missing something. I'm setting `currentNonce` to the `nonce` I'm creating from the `randomNonceString` method.

The `handleSignInWithAppleCompletion(_:)` doesn't fail. It succeeds, but crashes with the fatal error, as I would like it to if I have an **Invalid State**, i.e. no login request was sent. My `nonce` is not even instantiated, so my `currentNonce`, of course, is nil.

Why?

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import LocalAuthentication
import FirebaseAuth
import CryptoKit
import _AuthenticationServices_SwiftUI

final class SignInManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    
    private var currentNonce: String?
    
    // Adapted from https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/nonce#generate-a-cryptographically-random-nonce

    private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
        precondition(length > 0)
        let charset: [Character] =
        Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
        var result = ""
        var remainingLength = length
        
        while remainingLength > 0 {
            let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
                var random: UInt8 = 0
                let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
                if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                    fatalError(
                        "Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)"
                    )
                }
                return random
            }
            
            randoms.forEach { random in
                if remainingLength == 0 {
                    return
                }
                
                if random < charset.count {
                    result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                    remainingLength -= 1
                }
            }
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    @available(iOS 13, *)
    private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
        let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
        let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
        let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
            String(format: "%02x", $0)
        }.joined()
        
        return hashString
    }
}

extension SignInManager {
    func handleSignInWithAppleRequest(_ request: ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest) {
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let nonce = randomNonceString()
        currentNonce = nonce
        request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
    }
    
    func handleSignInWithAppleCompletion(_ result: Result<ASAuthorization, Error>) {
        if case .failure(let failure) = result {
            errorMessage = failure.localizedDescription
        }
        else if case .success(let success) = result {
            if let appleIDCredential = success.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
                guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
                    fatalError("Invalid state: a login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                }
                guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                    print("Unable to fetdch identify token.")
                    return
                }
                guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                                          idToken: idTokenString,
                                                          rawNonce: nonce)
                Task {
                    do {
                        let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
                        await updateDisplayName(for: result.user, with: appleIDCredential)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Error authenticating: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Fatal error: Invalid state: a login callback was received, but no login request was sent.**

> What did you try and what were you expecting?

• Rechecking my code
• Debugging in console
• Turning the music up

**UPDATE**

I attempted to deliberately create a request based on Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple?authuser=0&hl=en):

```
 func handleSignInWithAppleRequest(_ request: ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest) {
          let nonce = randomNonceString()
          currentNonce = nonce
          let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
          let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
          request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
          request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
    }
```

The line `let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()` changed nothing. Still working on solutions.

**Adding SignInButtonView**

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import AuthenticationServices

struct SignInButtonView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var signInManager: SignInManager
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // MARK: - Sign In With Apple
            HStack {
                SignInWithAppleButton { request in
                    SignInManager().handleSignInWithAppleRequest(request)
                } onCompletion: { result in
                    SignInManager().handleSignInWithAppleCompletion(result)
                }
                .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 50)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(width: 400)
    }
}

struct SignInButtonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignInButtonView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought - how do you register this ObservableObject in your view? As a StateObject or an ObservedObject? I suspect it might get evicted and the nonce might be nil.

Comment: Hi Peter. As an `ObservableObject`, as detailed above. Or do you mean in my `SignInButtonView` (should probably move this) where it's an `@EnvironmentObject`?

Comment: Updating with `SignInButtonView` now.

Comment: @PeterFriese So I tested with `@ObservedObject`, `@StateObject`, and `@EnvironmentObject`, and the result is always a nil `currentNonce`.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks mostly fine (it seems like it is based on the [sample app](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-video-samples/tree/main/fundamentals/apple/auth-sign-in-with-apple/final/Favourites) that goes along with the video about [Getting started with sign in with Apple using Firebase Authentication on Apple platforms](https://youtu.be/HyiNbqLOCQ8) I recently published).

However, there is a small, but significant typo: instead of referring to the `signInManager` property inside the `SignInWithAppleButton` completion handlers, you instantiate a new `SignInManager` every time you receive a callback.

This results in `currentNonce` being `nil` whenever you receive the second callback.

Change this:

```swift
SignInWithAppleButton { request in
  SignInManager().handleSignInWithAppleRequest(request)
} onCompletion: { result in
  SignInManager().handleSignInWithAppleCompletion(result)
}
```

to this:

```swift
SignInWithAppleButton { request in
  signInManager.handleSignInWithAppleRequest(request)
} onCompletion: { result in
  signInManager.handleSignInWithAppleCompletion(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this took forever.

The solution is obvious in hindsight, but I was following the docs too slavishly. Always learn what the docs are trying to get across about how the software works versus trusting the documentation.

I just needed to initialize the `currentNonce`

**Before**: `fileprivate var currentNonce: ?`
**After**: `fileprivate var currentNonce = String()`

Comment: Looking at your code, the issue is something else - I'll post an answer. BTW, did you type the code off of my [video](https://youtu.be/HyiNbqLOCQ8), or did you copy and paste it from the [repo](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-video-samples/tree/main/fundamentals/apple/auth-sign-in-with-apple/final/Favourites)?